# Count and Group By for products sold

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table Transaction & a table product as below .
Each Transaction has multiple products.

```
  ProductId Name
      1      ABC
      2      DEF
      3      GHI
```

Each transaction can have multiple products sold.

```
TransactionId ProductSoldInDept1 ProductSoldinDept2 ProductSoldinDept3
        1         1                       null         null
        2         1                        2           null
        3         3                        1           null
        4         2                        3             1
```

I am planning to generate a report and I would like to get a result something like this :

This shows the number of products sold per each department grouped by Id

**Expected Result :**

```
ProductID Department1ProdCount Department2ProdCount Department3ProdCount 
  1           2                           1             1                    
  2           1                           1             0
  3           1                           1             0
```

I could get till here , this is a query to get the counts for one specific product 
which is productid : 1
I would like to know how I could use a group by here :

```
select Count(CASE WHEN ProductSoldInDept1 = 1 THEN 1 END) ,
    Count(CASE WHEN ProductSoldInDept2 = 1 THEN 1 END) ,
      Count(CASE WHEN ProductSoldInDept3 = 1 THEN 1 END)
from   Table1
```

Comment: Why would you store sales per departments in columns instead of rows? Every time you add a new department you have to change all of your schema and all of your code?

Comment: I thought that I understood what you want, but your last query confused me. Can you post the expected result?

Comment: I apologize , there was an error in the query. I made a few changes . Would this be ok ?

Comment: Also do you really just store the product id in these columns? Where do you record how many of each product someone bought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  p.ProductID,
  Dept1ProdCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ProductSoldInDept1 = p.ProductID THEN 1 END),
  Dept2ProdCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ProductSoldInDept2 = p.ProductID THEN 1 END),
  Dept3ProdCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ProductSoldInDept3 = p.ProductID THEN 1 END)
FROM dbo.Product AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Transaction] AS t
ON p.ProductID IN  
  (t.ProductSoldInDept1, t.ProductSoldinDept2, t.ProductSoldinDept3)
GROUP BY p.ProductID;
```

**Result**

```
| PRODUCTID | DEPT1PRODCOUNT | DEPT2PRODCOUNT | DEPT3PRODCOUNT |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |              2 |              1 |              1 |
|         2 |              1 |              1 |              0 |
|         3 |              1 |              1 |              0 |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/feb6a/1)

Comment: +1 For the `Field = COUNT` thing... Hope you don't mind the edit.

Comment: Thanks Aaron ! Works Perfectly !  I also read your comments. The set of tables I have in the question are actually fictitious, but I have a similar problem at work. So I just created a scenario .Thank you for the suggestions , the answer  & the edit as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select ProductID, 
v.Department1ProdCount, v.Department2ProdCount, v.Department3ProdCount
from product a
cross apply 
(
 select Count(CASE WHEN ProductSoldInDept1 = a.ProductID THEN 1 END) Department1ProdCount,
 Count(CASE WHEN ProductSoldInDept2 = a.ProductID THEN 1 END) Department2ProdCount,
 Count(CASE WHEN ProductSoldInDept3 = a.ProductID THEN 1 END) Department3ProdCount
 from  Table1
) v
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
  TransactionId ProductSoldInDept1 ProductSoldinDept2 ProductSoldinDept3
    1         1                       null         null
    2         1                        2           null
    3         3                        1           null
    4         2                        3             1
```

might be better structured as this:

```
transid   prodsold    deptid
1         1           1
2         1           1
2         2           2
3         3           1
3         1           2
4         2           1
4         3           2
4         1           3
```

I think that would make your queries easier to write.

Comment: I made a similar comment without the demo, but this doesn't really answer the question (particularly if they can't change the schema).

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - I know and I agree.  I put this data in here based on your comment. I guess I think suggesting a potentially better way to do things is at least as valuable as directly answering the question on how to do it the "wrong" way. If I am wrong I will be down voted to death.